# How do I parse a text file and get a count of unique values?

Tags: python, list

I have file:

```
If MARA.MTART in ('ZPLW', 'ZFTW'), then MARA.PSTAT like '%K%'
If MARA.MTART in ('ZPLW', 'ZFTW'), then MARA.MATKL = '99999999'
```

and I want to parse it by, adding each Word after the "." to a list (MTART, PSTAT,MATKL) and if it is already in the list, to skip it.

so the list would be:

```
list = ['MTART', 'PSTAT', 'MATKL']
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Do you have access to GNU tools? As this operation can be more easily accomplished with `grep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Python:

This can easily be accomplished using regular expressions, via the `re` library. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) for the `.findall()` method can be found here.

The lines of the data file are iterated and the defined textual pattern is searched, with the results being populated to an output list. The duplicate values are dropped from the list using the `set()` function, as only unique values are allowed in a set.

Pattern explanation: `'\.([A-Z]+)'`

- Find a full stop (`.`)
- Search for and *capture* one or more upper case characters, and stop capturing when the first non-uppercase character is found.

Example code:

```
import re

rexp = re.compile('\.([A-Z]+)')
found = []

with open('./mara.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        found.extend(rexp.findall(line))
        
list(set(found))
```

Output:

```
['MTART', 'MATKL', 'PSTAT']
```

---

#### GNU:

On the other hand, if you'd like to use GNU tools instead, this can be accomplished using:

```
grep -Eo "\.([A-Z]+)" mara.csv | awk -F. '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Output:

```
MATKL
MTART
PSTAT
```

Comment: re.compile('\.([A-Z]+) will work only if the value after . is characters. By any chance there is number then this logic will fail

Comment: @manjari - Yes, this is by design.  Originally (before OP edited the post) there was an image of the file's contents and all requested values are uppercase character strings.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
txt="""\
If MARA.MTART in ('ZPLW', 'ZFTW'), then MARA.PSTAT like '%K%'
If MARA.MTART in ('ZPLW', 'ZFTW'), then MARA.MATKL = '99999999'"""
```

Just use a set comprehension:

```
>>> {w.partition('.')[2] for w in txt.split() if '.' in w}
{'MATKL', 'MTART', 'PSTAT'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
filename='yourcsv.csv'
with open(filename) as f: 
    ip = f.read()
test=list(set(re.findall(r'.\.(.*?) ', ip)))
print(test)

Output: ['MATKL', 'MTART', 'PSTAT']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk '{ gsub(_,     "", $!(NF = NF))
             sub("..",    "&"($__)"|",_)
            gsub("[|]+",          "|",_) } END {
            gsub("^\\^[|]|[|][$]$","",_)
 
 print _ }' FS='(^| )[^.]+MARA[.]| [^.]*$' OFS='|' \_='^|$'
```

=

```
MATKL|MTART|PSTAT
```